How do Algebraic functions happen to be important in the study of Riemann surfaces and arise naturally?
I am a Research Scholar and  I am trying to explore the connection between Algebraic functions and Branched coverings in the study of Riemann surface.Since,I am a beginner,I would like to have some motivation before diving into the formal treatment of Theorem-Proofs.Can someone give me some motivation as to why we are studying the Algebraic functions and what role they exactly play in the study of Riemann surfaces.It is always good to go from particular examples to general theory.So,I would like to see some motivating examples which we are trying to generalize/systematize/theorize through algebraic functions.
Can someone come up with an answer which would motivate me to study algebraic functions in the context of Riemann surfaces?
Thanks in advance.

What is your educational background? If you have no interest in algebraic functions and solving polynomial equations, maybe you should first study algebra before learning about Riemann surfaces.

@MoisheKohan Please be respectful,.I never said that I have no interest in algebraic function as you might be presuming,(don't know why though).By 'Why we are studying algebraic functions' I actually meant why they occur naturally in the context of Riemann surface.And my educational background is already given if you are not aware.
